# How to add html link in first paragraph of tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to add HTML link in the first paragraph of TinyMCE and all paragraphs disabled. How can I fix it? Please help.

```
mode : "exact",
elements:"home_textarea",
theme : "advanced",
plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",
gecko_spellcheck : true,

// Theme options
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "code",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
theme_advanced_resizing : true,
```

I want the 'code' of  `theme_advanced_buttons2` in `theme_advanced_buttons1`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,code",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
```